# How sqlkata can wrap table name with dots into square brackets?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlkata

I would like to get query like this.

```sql
INSERT INTO [z_odv_17.02.2018] ([Val1], [Val2]) VALUES (@p0, @p1)
```

But sqlkata compile this query slightly different.

```sql
INSERT INTO [z_odv_17].[02].[2018] ([Val1], [Val2]) VALUES (@p0, @p1)
```

How to wrap whole table name with dots into brackets? Or as alternative way, how to make sqlkata ignore dots?

Basicly, I need sqlkata to compile a name like `[z_odv_17.02.2018]` instead of `[z_odv_17].[02].[2018]`.

I have tried to use `FromRaw`, but `System.InvalidCastException` was thrown. It cannot cast from `SqlKata.RawFromClause` to `SqlKata.FromClause`.

Code piece to reproduce error.

```cs
var name = "[z_odv_17.02.2018]";
var sql = new Query()
.FromRaw(name)
.AsInsert(new
{
    Val1 = 1,
    Val2 = true
});

var mssql = new SqlServerCompiler();

var mssqlResult = mssql.Compile(sql);

var mssqlText = mssqlResult.Sql;
```

Comment: Validated as a bug, could you please open an issue on https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/issues

Comment: @amd done https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/issues/295